# How to partition a area using k-mean in r?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have this exemple of clustering data

```
library(cluster)
library(fpc)

input = data.frame(Lon = c(43,43.2,43.5,43.8,44), Lat = c(-12,-11.5,-13,-14,-10.5), Var = c(5,4,7,8,8))

clus <- kmeans(input, centers = 3)

plotcluster(input, clus$cluster)

r <- clusplot(input, clus$cluster, color = T, shade = T, labels = 2, lines = 0)
```

I want to draw red lines who partition points like show the exemple below.

[image]

Comment: What you are looking for is called a Voronoi diagram.  There is an R function to get those in the `dismo` package.

Comment: It seems strange to mix locational data (Lat, Lon) with other kinds of data (Var). Two observations could be in the same cluster because they are near one another in space, but not near in value or near one another in value but not in space. Also, if you use more than 2 variables in the cluster analysis, you cannot guarantee that the clusters will plot as separate groups in 2 dimensions.